# The meaning of "whereunto"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, semantics, where, where-which

What is the meaning of "whereunto" here?

> Dionysius the elder, after having, by a tedious siege and elty of Dionysius
> through exceeding great difficulties, taken the city of Reggio, the Tyrant. and in it the governor Phyton, a very gallant man, who had
> made so obstinate a defence, was resolved to make him a tragical example of his revenge: ***in order whereunto he first told him***, “That he had the day before caused his son and all his kindred to be drowned.” To which Phyton returned no other answer but this : " That they were then by one day happier than he,”…

From “The Essays of Montaigne”

It does not make sense to me if it means "to which".

Comment: Work out what the antecedent of whereunto/"to which" is, and then substitute it in. It should fall into place, something like "in order to make him a tragical example of his revenge he first told him..."

Comment: Can you Post a real example, citing the source?